# Scrolling Parallax Issues — posY Jumping

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm working on a site based on this: http://inner.geek.nz/javascript/parallax/

All's well except I'm getting a jump down (by whatever px is set in `calcParallax(xx, x, posY)`)
on scroll. This number should be where the image ends not where it begins — it should begin `scrollTop` or 0. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've pretty much taken the structure verbatim from the above link without the `#cloud` object or relevant script.

Here's what I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function calcParallax(tileheight, speedratio, scrollposition) {
 return ((tileheight) - (Math.floor(scrollposition / speedratio) % (tileheight+1)));
}

window.onload = function() {

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var posX = (document.documentElement.scrollLeft) ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : window.pageXOffset;
    var posY = (document.documentElement.scrollTop) ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset;
    
    var ground = document.getElementById('ground');
    var groundparallax = calcParallax(53, 8, posY);
    ground.style.backgroundPosition = "0 " + groundparallax + "px "; 

  document.getElementById('javascriptcode').onscroll = function() {
    var posX = (this.scrollLeft) ? this.scrollLeft : this.pageXOffset;
    var j = calcParallax(53, 16, posX);
    console.log('scroll js: '+ j);
    document.getElementById('javascriptcode').style.backgroundPosition = j + "px 0";
  }
}

</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I am having the same issue with that script as well. Cant figure out how to fix it either, but Ive put it into JSFiddle. Theres actually 2 jumps, right at the beginning and right at the end of the first cloud: http://jsfiddle.net/LTcsQ/

Answer (score 1):

Use this example instead. It uses a different jQuery that seems more stable and does not jump around like the script from inner geek.

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/backgroundparallax.html

Answer (score 0):

I put together a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/gCwAm/) on something similar while trying to minimize scripting in the scroll event... I've found that it's jumpy in Firefox and Chrome, and oddly smooth as silk in IE.

Even this [game website](http://www.elderscrolls.com/skyrim/overview/) that uses a combination of Mootools and CSS transitions is a bit jumpy.

CSS

```
/* Tiled background image */
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 /* Use height of header image for top position */
 background: #000 url(http://i201.photobucket.com/albums/aa236/Mottie1/testsite/forums/bgtile.jpg) left 1080px repeat-y;
}
/* Top background image (1920x1080) */
#wrapper {
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: url(http://i201.photobucket.com/albums/aa236/Mottie1/testsite/forums/bg1.jpg) center top repeat-x;
 z-index: 100;
}
/* Page Title image */
#header {
 height: 350px;
 background: url(http://i201.photobucket.com/albums/aa236/Mottie1/testsite/forums/title.png) center 40px no-repeat;
}
/* Content Block with 55% opacity background image */
.block { 
 width: 600px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 border: #333 1px solid;
 padding: 20px;
 background: url(http://i201.photobucket.com/albums/aa236/Mottie1/testsite/forums/bg-black-55.png);
}
.block h3 {
 font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
 font-size: 130%;
}
```

HTML

```
<body> <!-- contains repeated background image -->
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- contains top image -->

<div id="header"></div> <!-- contains the page title image -->

 <div class="block"> <!-- contains 55% opacity background image -->
  <h3>Block 1</h3>
  <div class="content">Content 1.</div>
 </div>

 <div class="block">
  <h3>Block 2</h3>
  <div class="content">Content 2.</div>
 </div>

 <div class="block">
  <h3>Block 3</h3>
  <div class="content">Content 3.</div>
 </div>

 <div class="block">
  <h3>Block 4</h3>
  <div class="content">Content 4.</div>
 </div>

 <div class="block">
  <h3>Block 5</h3>
  <div class="content">Content 5.</div>
 </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // defaults
  var st, win = $(window)[0],
   body = $('body')[0],
   doc = (jQuery.support.boxModel) ? document.documentElement : document.body,
   wrap = $('#wrapper')[0],

   // Set top background image height here
   imgH = 1080; // top image height

  // vertical parallax scroll
  $(win).scroll(function(){
   st = (win.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop );
   if (st < imgH) { wrap.style.backgroundPosition = 'center ' + (st/4) + 'px'; } // limit moving top image only when in view
   body.style.backgroundPosition = 'left ' + ( imgH + st/4) + 'px';
  });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your 53 to the exact height of each element.

The only thing I can't figure out about this script is it jumps slightly vertically when I change it to a scroll left function.

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
    var elementparallax = calcParallax(7000, .5, posX);
    element.style.backgroundPosition = " 0" + elementparallax + "px";
  };
```

P.S. You can change the vertical scroll to horizontal by changing posY to posX and in = "0_" + elementparalax to = "_0"